# How to dynamically use Object Name in the List in Apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass a dynamic value in the List to store the data from a respective object. But, this code is throwing me an error - 'Unexpected <'. Please help.

```
public static void delRecords(List<Object> sfdata, string objApi){

   List<Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objApi)> sData = sfdata;
   
   delete sfdata;
   System.debug(sfdata.Id);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use dynamic typing in apex; it is a statically typed language. The best you can do is hold a list of a base class. Here that would be a `List<SObject>`. If possible provide the list as `List<SObject>` to the method otherwise you will have to write a loop converting each entry in the input list of `Object` to an `SObject` before adding it to the `List<SObject>`, which is relatively slow and inefficient but necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic typing in Apex; it is a statically typed language. The best you can do is hold a list of a base class. Here that would be a `List<SObject>` to pass to the `delete` DML operation. `SObject` is a base class for every SObject type (such as `Account` or `MyCustomObject__c`). Note that `SObject` is a subclass of `Object` (the ultimate base class for all Apex classes) which is why, if the data in appropriate, you can cast `Object` to `SObject`.

If possible provide the list as `List<SObject>` to the method otherwise you will have to write a loop converting each entry in the input list of `Object` to an `SObject` before adding it to the `List<SObject>`, which is relatively slow and inefficient but necessary.

```java
public static void delRecords(List<Object> sfdata) {
   List<SObject> sData = new List<SObject>();

   for (Object entry : sfdata) {
       sData.add((SObject) entry);
   }
   
   delete sData;
}
```

Note that if the `sfdata` includes any instances that are NOT some form of `SObject` this function will throw an exception when trying to perform the cast in the for loop.

Comment: As always, you ROCK @Phil!!!!. I got what I exactly wanted. You are truly an Expert. It takes ages for me to get to the solution. :(

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't help in this situation, and Phil W's answer is the correct one, I got here when looking at how to List with a dynamic type, and it turns out it IS possible by using `Type.forName`.

For example, the following is possible:

```
Type.forName( 'List<' + objApi + '>' ).newInstance()
```

This means you can, for example:

```
List<Object> dynamicList = (List<Object>)Type.forName( 'List<' + objApi + '>' ).newInstance();
```

If you know a common ancestor for all the possible types, you could cast to that type, for example, if you know that objApi is the name of an SObject:

```
List<SObject> dynamicList = (List<SObject>)Type.forName( 'List<' + objApi + '>' ).newInstance();
```

However, what you can't do is dynamically specify the type of the variable itself.

I.E. that's nothing equivalent to:

```
List<objApi> dynamicList = (List<SObject>)Type.forName( 'List<' + objApi + '>' ).newInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks Rob.. It helps. But unfortunately, I can mark only 1 answer :(

Comment: No worries - it's not about the ticks, it's about being helpful!